# emacs opens py file as sh file

Tags: python, shell

Emacs has opened a `py` file as a shell script. What went wrong and how to change?

[image]

Comment: (describe-variable 'auto-mode-alist)  probably  wrong for sh-mode. check your init file.

Comment: Failing that, what is the very first line of the file?

Comment: @phils, the first line is `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Comment: @giglair, there is nothing about `(describe-variable 'auto-mode-alist) ` in the `emacs ` init file.

Comment: If you run `emacs -Q` and open the file, does the same thing happen?  If so, what does `M-x emacs-version` report?  If not, the issue is somewhere in your own config.

Comment: Regardless, `C-h i g (emacs)Choosing Modes` and `(elisp)Auto Major Mode` detail all of the mechanisms used to determine the major mode for a file.

Comment: @phils, now `emacs` open the file normally without any intervention from me.

Comment: If you mean that `emacs -Q` (and `emacs -q` as well?) opens the file in `python-mode` but plain `emacs` (using your config) still opens it in `sh-mode`, then the problem is somewhere in your own config, and so you will need to debug your config to find out why.  Recursive bisection is a good approach, commenting out half of the remaining elisp each time to narrow it down to the code which is responsible.